# Very basic conditional probability question.

Tags: probability

A box contains 4 white balls and 3 red balls . In succession, two balls are randomly selected and removed from the box. Given that first ball removed is white, the probability that second ball removed red is ?

---

Solution is $P(\frac RW)$ = $\frac{P(R \cap W)}{P(W)}$

$P(\frac RW) = \frac{P(R)\cdot P(W)}{P(W)}= \frac{\frac 36 \cdot \frac 47}{\frac 47} = \frac 12 $

Here in numerator , they have multiplied the probabilities because P(R) and P(W) are independent. But how are they independent? After picking W, I am not putting W back again. So the probability of R would depend on W right as the total number of balls changes after picking one W ball first ?

By logic and intuition, I can figure out that the answer is indeed 0.5 . But can someone please help me to arrive at this answer using the conditional probability formula ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Sure.  More simply, with one white ball removed the box contains three of each, so of course the answer is $\frac 12$.

Comment: You are right that events "drawing a white ball first" and drawing a red ball are not independent. Thus the correct formula is  (P(R **|W** )*P(W))/(P(W)) But you have to define the variables W and R first. I´ve made some assumptions.

Comment: @lulu, Yes, using logic I can figure out that it is 1/2. But how do I get the answer using conditional probability formula?

Comment: Your notation is misleading.  What events are $W,R$?  Better to have events $W_1,R_2$ where the subscript indicates which draw you speak of.  It is clear, then that $W_1,R_2$ are dependent events as knowing that you got a white first increases the probability that you got a red second.

Comment: P(W) is the probability of drawing a white ball. P(R) is the probability of drawing a red ball. Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to approach this problem as a conditional probability exercise, you can proceed as follows. Define $R_1$ first ball is red, $R_2$ second ball is red, and $W_1$ first ball is white, we have

\begin{align}
P(R_2|W_1) &= \frac{P(R_2\cap W_1)}{P(W_1)}=\frac{P(W_1|R_2)\cdot P(R_2)}{P(W_1)}\\
&=\frac{P(W_1|R_2)\cdot (P(R_2|W_1)\cdot P(W_1)+P(R_2|R_1)\cdot P(R_1))}{P(W_1)}.
\end{align}

We know $P(W_1) = \frac{4}{7}$, $P(R_1) = \frac{3}{7}$ and $P(W_1|R_2)=P(W_1) = \frac{4}{7}$. If you let $P(R_2|W_1)=x$, and $P(R_2|R_1)=1-x$, the above becomes

\begin{align}
x = \frac{(4/7)\cdot(x\cdot(4/7)+(1-x)\cdot(3/7))}{4/7}
\end{align}

Solve and you get $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is **given** that the first ball was white this problem has nothing to do with conditional probability. After the first draw we are univocally left with an urn containing three red and three white balls. The probability that we then draw a red ball is obviously ${1\over2}$.

Comment: Sir, but the definition of conditional probability is that probability of event A given that event B has already occurred. So here the event B is drawing a white ball which has already occurred. So, why is it not conditional then?